# How to determine the "number of pages" a user can access in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

My company wishes to perform a security scan on the server that we use to host our Jenkins installation (version 2.222.1); as part of this, I have been asked how many "pages" a user account could access - where a "page" is of component type is ‘text/html’ or ‘aspx’

Can anyone tell me how to calculate this, please?

Comment: "Many". I suppose telling Sec. team "that's a stupid measure" won't help. Think about it .. via the UI; every page under the configure settings, then every job: status, changes, configure, build (with params), email template, move, rename, BFA x2,  Job Config History, any other plugin pages, then workspace! Every file in workspace has 2 pages. How many jobs and how big is your source? Run a web crawler (httrack) against your site and give him a number. Make sure you are [Securing Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/securing-jenkins/) befote you let him at it.

Comment: Also, you probably want to read the [Jenkins Security Advisories](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisories/) and move up to the [latest LTS](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide) - [Changelog](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable), at least to 2.263.4.